# Show a message if user does NOT exist in the DB

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have 4 conditions.

1. If nothing is filled, go to a page. <--- Working fine
2. If username or password is wrong, go to a page. <--- Working fine
3. If username is not activated, go to a page. <--- Working fine
4. If username does not exist in the DB, go to a page. <--- Not Working :(

But I'm having trouble with my fourth condition: It does not go to the desired page, `/account/no/`.

What am I doing wrong? This is the relevant piece of code for the fourth condition:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
# 4th condition IF USER NOT EXIST, then go to /ACCOUNT/NO

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
  $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysqli_error());
  $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  if( $num_row ==1 )

  {


if ($_POST['username']!=$row['username']) 
{
  header('Location: /account/no/');
  exit;
    }
  }
```

HTML Login Form:

```
<form action="/login/" action="post">
<input name="username" type="text">
<input name ="password" type="password">
<input name="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that $num_row is not equal to 1 if the username does not exist. The code should look like the following:

```
if($num_row ==1)

{

//do action

 } else if($num_row ==0){
header('Location: /account/no/');
 exit;
}
```